# Fetch json data from two different url in reach native?

Tags: json, react-native, fetch

I'm new in react native and I try to learn fetch data.

I have got this source to work:
[Fetch data in react native](https://medium.com/@nutanbhogendrasharma/step-by-step-consume-json-data-in-react-native-mobile-app-b86d837901da)

But how do I if I want to fetch json from two different sources?

Link1
https://mobile.xa-speakers.org/fellowships.json

Link2
https://mobile.xa-speakers.org/mobile.json

I need then to get source from link1 who have same id in link2

Please can someone show me example on this?? I would like it to be in function based component.

Comment: Look up CORS, if you understand the basics, this should be easy.

Comment: Execute the first request and save the results in an array or list.  Then iterate over the collection executing the second request